# While installing mcube module using pip install, I am getting below error even if I have installed CS C++ build tool 14

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, 3d-modelling, stable-diffusion

```
Processing c:\users\kunal saxena\stable-dreamfusion\pymcubes
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy (from PyMCubes==0.1.4)
  Downloading numpy-1.24.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (14.9 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 14.9/14.9 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting scipy>=1.0.0 (from PyMCubes==0.1.4)
  Downloading scipy-1.10.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (42.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 42.2/42.2 MB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: PyMCubes
  Building wheel for PyMCubes (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for PyMCubes (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\mcubes
      copying mcubes\exporter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\mcubes
      copying mcubes\numpy_smoothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\mcubes
      copying mcubes\smoothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\mcubes
      copying mcubes\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\mcubes
      copying mcubes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\mcubes
      running build_ext
      building 'mcubes._mcubes' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\mcubes
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\mcubes\src
      cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -Imcubes/src "-IC:\Users\KUNAL SAXENA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_oa3rgic\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -IC:\Anaconda\envs\venv\include -IC:\Anaconda\envs\venv\Include /EHsc /Tpmcubes/src/_mcubes.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\mcubes/src/_mcubes.obj -std=c++11 -Wall
      error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMCubes
Failed to build PyMCubes
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyMCubes, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

```
(venv) C:\Users\KUNAL SAXENA\stable-dreamfusion>cd PyMCubes

(venv) C:\Users\KUNAL SAXENA\stable-dreamfusion\PyMCubes>pip install .
```

after this getting above error.

Comment: Do you have to compile `PyMCube` from source or could you also use the latest release version for which whl files exist?

Comment: There is not much of an error message, other than `error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None`, try manually running `cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -Imcubes/src "-IC:\Users\KUNAL SAXENA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_oa3rgic\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -IC:\Anaconda\envs\venv\include -IC:\Anaconda\envs\venv\Include /EHsc /Tpmcubes/src/_mcubes.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\mcubes/src/_mcubes.obj -std=c++11 -Wall` and see if that gives you more error messages to go by